# How to override the existing onclick() methods of html anchor tags

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

In a HTML page there are couple of anchor tags with onclick() methods - of which codes I cannot or must not change. However, I can add a new js file or jQuery to this page. How can I add an event listener for click events of those anchor tags - which must be fired/called before those existing onclick() methods? After that the existing onclick() methods should be called. Something like the following.

```
<a href='#' class="edit" onclick='edit()'>Edit First</a>
<a href='#' class="edit" onclick='edit()'>Edit Second</a>
<a href='#' class="edit" onclick='edit()'>Edit Third</a>
```

and

```
const el = document.getElementsByClassName("edit");
el.addEventListener("click", beforeEdit, false);

function beforeEdit() {
 //this should be called before edit(), after that edit() must be called.
}
```

Comment: Extracting the text and then attempting to run it should like a recipe for disaster as it would likely need something like [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)  *"**Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk.**"*

Answer (score 0):

Remove the attribute, then call `edit` yourself in your own handler. Also you'll need to iterate over the elements properly - `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection, not an element.

```
for (const anchor of document.querySelectorAll('.edit')) {
  anchor.removeAttribute('onclick');
  anchor.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // insert your function code here, then:
    edit();
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply! How can I get/retrieve that body of edit() method using js especially if there are different edit methods such as edit1(), edit2() etc ?

Comment: I guess you could cast it to a string to read the source text, but there should rarely be a need for that I think

Answer (score 0):

> how can get/retrieve that body of edit() method using js and execute it

In other words, your requirement is that the `onclick="edit()"` is not always `edit()`.

You *could* use [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) but even the MDN page states:

> *"**Executing JavaScript from a string is an enormous security risk.**"*

An alternative, to ensure your code runs first is to insert your code at the start of the `onclick=`, eg:

```
$(".edit").attr("onclick", (i, attr) => "beforeEdit();"+attr);
```

Example snippet:

```js
$(".edit").attr("onclick", (i, attr) => "beforeEdit();"+attr);

function beforeEdit() {
  console.log("before edit");
}

function edit() {
  console.log("edit");
}
function edit2() {
  console.log("edit2");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href='#' class="edit" onclick='edit()'>Edit First</a>
<a href='#' class="edit" onclick='edit2()'>Edit Second</a>
<a href='#' class="edit" onclick='edit()'>Edit Third</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since event attributes are fired at the *target* or *bubbling* phases, you can add a [capturing event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#bubbling_and_capturing_explained) on these elements, and wrap their content in a new element so that the event actually fires on the child:

```js
let val = 0;
const els = document.querySelectorAll(".edit");
els.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", beforeEdit, {capture: true}));

function beforeEdit() {
  console.log("setting global val to ", val = Math.random());
}
function edit() {
  console.log("global val is now", val);
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<a href='#' class="edit" onclick='edit()'><span>Edit First</span></a>
<a href='#' class="edit" onclick='edit()'><span>Edit Second</span></a>
<a href='#' class="edit" onclick='edit()'><span>Edit Third</span></a>
```

Or, maybe cleaner, you can attach the event handler on a parent:

```js
let val = 0;
document.body.addEventListener("click", beforeEdit, {capture: true});

function beforeEdit(evt) {
  if (evt.target.matches("a.edit,a.edit *")) {
    console.log("setting global val to ", val = Math.random());
  }
}
function edit() {
  console.log("global val is now", val);
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<a href='#' class="edit" onclick='edit()'>Edit First</a>
<a href='#' class="edit" onclick='edit()'>Edit Second</a>
<a href='#' class="edit" onclick='edit()'>Edit Third</a>
```